# Search word from certain line GREP

Tags: search, text, grep

```
File type = "ooTextFile"
Object class = "TextGrid"

xmin = 0 
xmax = 82.7959410430839 
tiers? <exists> 
size = 1 
item []: 
    item [1]:
        class = "IntervalTier" 
        name = "ortho" 
        xmin = 0 
        xmax = 82.7959410430839 
        intervals: size = 6 
        intervals [1]:a
            xmin = 0 
            xmax = 15.393970521541949 
            text = "Aj tento rok organizuje Rádio  Sud piva. Kto chce súťažiť, nemusí sa nikde registrovať.  
        intervals [2]:
            xmin = 15.393970521541949 
            xmax = 27.58997052154195 
              .
              .  
              .
```

Hi I am working with hundreds of text files like this.
I want to filter all values `xmin=...` from this text file but only from `16th` line because at the start there are `xmins` which are useless as you can see.

I tried:

```
cat text.txt | grep xmin
```

but it shows all lines where `xmin` is.

Please help me. I can't modify text files because I need to work with hundreds of them  so I have to design suitable way how to filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` and `grep` to look for "xmin" from 16th line till the end of a single file:

```
sed -n '16,$p' foobar.txt | grep "xmin"
```

In case of multiple files here is a `bash` script to get the output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$1"/*; do
output=$(sed -n '16,$p' "$file" | grep "xmin")
if [[ -n $output ]]; then
echo -e "$file has follwoing entries:\n$output"; fi; done
```

Run the script as `bash script.sh /directory/containing/the/files/to/be/searched`

Comment: This works ok for first file, but if you have `file1` and  `file2`, This `sed -n '16,$p' file* | grep "xmin"` gives all  `xmin` from second file.

Comment: thanks a lot. I've got what I want using: "sed -n '16,$p' text.txt | grep "xmin\|xmax"| cut -d '=' -f2" I wanted to filter xmin also xmax values but only numbers and it works :) But I also wanted to have these values in two colums. One column for xmin values and another column for xmax values. Is it possible to divide this values to two columns? Something like that:
0              15,39397
15,3937    27,5899

Comment: @Nikolaus: Yes, its possible using `column` command: `sed -n '16,$p' text.txt | grep "xmin\|xmax"| cut -d '=' -f2 | column`

Comment: @Nikolaus: you can also try `sed -n '16,$p' test.txt | grep "xmin\|xmax"| cut -d '=' -f2 | tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: @Nikolaus: I see, you want two columns but the example in the comment was somewhat misleading....you ok with python in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk 'FNR>15 && /xmin/' file*
            xmin = 0
            xmin = 15.393970521541949
```

It show all `xmin` from line `16`

---

You can also print file name of the found  `xmin`

```
awk 'FNR>15 && /xmin/ {$1=$1;print FILENAME" -> "$0}' file*
file22 -> xmin = 0
file22 -> xmin = 15.393970521541949
```

Update:  Need to be `FNR` to work with multiple files.